# Using AsEnumerable and allowing Null values

Tags: sql, xml, vb.net, dataset

I am loading the dataset table values into a .xml table.  I then email this table if there are results.  How can I load null columns into the .xml table below?   FOr example _New_Invoice_Number will occasionally be Null because it is a nullable value.

```
 Dim void = _
            <html>
                <body>
                    <table border="1">
                        <tr><th>Store #</th><th>Invoice Date</th><th>Invoice #</th><th>Vehicle Tag</th><th>Void Reason</th><th>Invoice Total</th><th>New Invoice #</th><th>Vehicle Tag</th><th>New Invoice Total</th><th>Re-Tendered?</th><th>User Name</th></tr>
                        <%= From vtest In Me.DataDeliveryServiceDataSet.datatable.AsEnumerable _
                            Select <tr><td><%= vtest.Store_Number %></td>
                                       <td><%= Convert.ToDateTime(vtest.Invoice_Date).ToString("M/d/yy") %></td>
                                       <td><%= vtest.Invoice_Number %></td>
                                       <td><%= vtest.Vehicle_Tag %></td>
                                       <td><%= vtes.Void_Reason %></td>
                                       <td><%= vtest.Invoice_Total %></td>
                                       <td><%= vtest._New_Invoice__ %></td>
                                       <td><%= vtest._Vehicle_Tag %></td>
                                       <td><%= vtest.New_Invoice_Total %></td>
                                       <td><%= vtest._Re_tendered_ %></td>
                                       <td><%= vtest.User_Name %></td></tr> %>
                    </table>
                </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: It seems like you are giving us lots of unnecessary details and lots of code in order to ask a very simple question.  The problem is that I'm having trouble figuring out what exactly that simple question is.

Comment: Much better.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim a As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Dim b As String

    Dim c = IIf(IsNothing(a), "", a.ToString())
    Dim d = IIf(IsNothing(b), "", b)
End Sub

<td><%= IIf(IsNothing(vtest.Vehicle_Tag), "", vtest.Vehicle_Tag) %></td>
<td><%= IIf(IsNothing(vtest.Invoice_Number), "", vtest.Invoice_Number.ToString()) %></td>
```

Another option is to handle Null's on the SQL side:

```
select coalesce(Vehicle_Tag, '') from myTable
```

Comment: No go.  I have a type of "Decimal" and "Integer" for 2 of the columns.  If I try .tostring it does not work.

Comment: I'm completely lost here... Where would I call on that in the xml build?

Comment: <td><%= IIf(IsNothing(vtest.Invoice_Number), "", vtest.Invoice_Number.ToString()) %></td>

Comment: isNothing is not a valid vb.net trigger... I tried:
`<td><%= IIf(vtest.Is_New_Invoice__Null, "", vtest._New_Invoice__.ToString) %></td>`

Comment: According to MSDN it is valid, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5adx7fxz(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: That's just it. It doesn't error... It runs' the program, however doesn't email any results. I know for a fact there are results. However, If I pick a date that does not have null values in the 3 fields (New Invoice number, New Vehicle tag, and New invoice total) it sends the results via email just fine. ONLY on days where there are null values it does NOT send.  If I run the query from the dataset, it returns the result... so it's on the build of the xml that it errors..

Comment: Did you try to put a break point on this line of code and then analyse the values/types you are having an issue with? You can press Ctrl + Alt + I to open an Immediate window and play around with the options we discussed.

Comment: I did, but it will not show values anywhere... It's a dataset that scrolls... so it has multiple values.  Breakpoints do not help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15289/discussion-between-dmitriy-and-shmewnix)